# Truncate column in data frame from float to int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) that has an `Age` column, and looks like

```
              Age
0       59.917864
1       50.387406
2       50.387406
3       55.008898
```

I am trying to crearte a new column call `Age_truncated` which would be the `Age` column as an integer and would look like:

```
              Age  Age_truncated
0       59.917864             59  
1       50.387406             50
2       50.387406             50
3       55.008898             55
```

I have tried:

```
df[("Age_truncated")] = df["Age"].astype(int)
df["Age_truncated"] = int(df["Age"])
```

without success.  What further things could I try?

Comment: `df["Age"].astype(int)` should work, even with the parentheses in `df[("Age_truncated")]` (you don't need them). What error do you receive when you try `df["Age_truncated") = df["Age"].astype(int)`?

Comment: Thanks, there is no error message it just stops.....

Comment: This works for me. What do you mean "it just stops"? Python crashes? `None` is returned? An exception is thrown?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the program gets to the line  df["Age_truncated"] = df["Age"].astype(int) and then stops.  I have a print statement straight after which does not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `floor` from `numpy`

```
df['Age1']=np.floor(df.Age).astype(int)
df
Out[414]: 
         Age  Age1
0  59.917864    59
1  50.387406    50
2  50.387406    50
3  55.008898    55
```

Comment: Did you reproduce OP's problem?